# Can boot (power off, restart) but cannot reboot

Tags: linux, grub2, reboot, bios

Endeavouros Linux (Arch); non-UEFI PC.

I have dual booted my PC (Windows/Endeavouros). When I power-on my PC I get the Grub2 menu and all is well.

When I `sudo reboot`, or `sudo shutdown -r now` (I know they're the same thing), or select `reboot` from the desktop environment, the computer shuts down but on soft-restart it does not find grub, instead I get:

```
reboot and select proper Boot device or Insert Boot Media
in selected Boot device and press a key
```

So when I power off my PC and restart, it finds the correct boot media but when I `reboot` it does not.

If I reboot from Windows, the reboot just works and the grub2 menu is found. This (and the fact that I can power-off and restart) suggests to me that the BIOS settings are OK.

I have tried to reinstall grub and do `grub-mkconfig` etc. but in the reboot sequence it doesn't get as far as grub. I have ignored this problem for over a year now, because shutting down and restarting as opposed to `reboot`ing is not a big deal and trying to solve this issue was wasting a lot of time.

But it's beginning to bug me and I just don't understand what's going on. The PC doesn't get as far as loading the Grub2 menu on reboot so it can't be the fault of grub or the grub settings and the BIOS settings allow the power-on/start-up and power-on/start-up **or** reboot from Windows to work perfectly.

Q: Given the above behaviour, what does `shutdown` do (or not do) that `reboot` does not do (or does)?